# why c# continuewith pass exception?

Tags: c#, exception, async-await, try-catch, rethrow

I'm trying to handle task exceptions without await.
I am trying to use ContinueWith with TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion. But i have one main problem - in test program everything goes well and works only code from ContinueWith. But in my main program Exception still goes to catch block and to ContinueWith (function doesn't stop working but I want to work with this exceptions in other way).

Small example looks like this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Testim();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("catch");
        }

    }

    static void method()
    {
        HttpClient cl=new HttpClient();
        cl.PostAsync("http://oru.uri", null);
    }

    static void Testim()
    {
        HttpClient cl = new HttpClient();
        Task t = cl.PostAsync("http://oru.uri", null);
        t.ContinueWith((Task t1) => { Console.WriteLine("success"); }, CancellationToken.None,
            TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.Current);
        t.ContinueWith((Task t1) => { Console.WriteLine("error"); }, CancellationToken.None,
            TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.Current);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

In test project everything okay, but in my other project exeptions handle 2 times - in catch and in continuewith and catch executes first.

Comment: You never Start() or await a task. And print the exception, at least the message.

Comment: This is console application (test program and main)

Comment: I never start task but it's working, in main prject and in test too...

Comment: You don't need to 'start' a task here @bommelding

Comment: @АлександрПодорин I'm having reproducing this. Using .Net fiddle I get the expected behaviour, where only the continuation for OnlyOnFaulted is being called  https://dotnetfiddle.net/YrvCZJ

Comment: You need to provide code which behaves in unexpected way (from the other project), because with code you provided it seems it can't behave in a way you describe.

Comment: Hmmm
I think I understand problem of my code
After this I am doing Wait for tasks but some of them may be already cancelled or faulted and then it crash

Answer (score 0):

Problem of my code (not this example) was that I Wait() task. 
But when I receive exception before Wait() then Wait generate Exception